# Using Firebase Storage from nodejs with the client sdk version 9

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a set of cli scripts that users inside our company use to maintain our application. The scripts run in node and use user logins ([the client sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node)) and **not** [the admin sdk](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin), so that users of the script don't have full access to the application. I previously had this working with node v12 and the firebase sdk version 7. For a bunch of reasons we have updated everything to run in node v18 and firebase version 9. The only snag I have is that I can't get firebase storage upload to work.

It seems `uploadBytes()` never completes.

The JS SDK says that [node.js is supported](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/environments-js-sdk) for firebase storage. Here's a minimal example that shows the problem:

```
    import fs from 'node:fs';
    import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
    import { getAuth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from 'firebase/auth';
    import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable } from 'firebase/storage';

    const firebaseConfig = (await import('./config.mjs')).default;
    const userCredentials = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./credentials.json').toString());

    initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    (async () => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      const storage = getStorage();
      let { user } = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, userCredentials.email, userCredentials.password);

      // valid path in storage rules
      let storageRef = ref(storage, `users/${user.uid}/test.jpg`);
      // invalid path in storage rules
      // let storageRef = ref(storage, 'invalid');
      
      // trying with different types of buffers, same result
      const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, fs.createReadStream('./test.jpg'));
      // const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, fs.readFileSync('./test.jpg'));
      // const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, Uint8Array.from(fs.readFileSync('./test.jpg')));
      
      // I have tried with uploadBytes() but this doesn't have an on() method to capture events.
      // Using uploadBytes() has the same result.
      
      uploadTask.on('state_changed', x => console.log('progress:', x), console.error, console.log);
      await uploadTask;
      console.log('this is never printed');
      await signOut(auth);
      console.log('done');
    })();
```

Interesting observations:

- It works just fine to download a file (see snippet below)
- I'm **not** seeing the allows and denies show up in the rules monitoring tool in the Firebase Console when I run this with a valid or invalid storage path, so it's as if the request is never made
- When I use `uploadBytesResumable()` and pass in callback functions for progress, error, and complete, I get one immediate firing of the progress function with a `state: "running"` but nothing else ever fires.
- I get the same behavior with various types of buffers and streams
- I get the same behavior with `uploadBytes()` except that the returned promise doesn't seem to have the capability to add event handlers.

This code works for downloading the file in the body of the above function:

```
    let stream = getStream(storageRef);
    stream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./test-write.jpg'));
    stream.on('end', console.log);
```

I'm using firebase@9.9.4 installed by npm and nodejs 18.1.

Comment: This seems to be working for me with `readFileSync()`. You don't need a Read stream here. Can you try this [gist](https://gist.github.com/DharmarajX24/50f443db1b17ce7927ae0a89d47b9d78) and run it?

Comment: You can see in my example that I already tried `readFileSync` and `uploadBytes` - at any rate I tried your example and get the same behavior. The promise never returns. Are you using the same sdk and node versions as me? I can try your sdk version if you're using a different one. I don't see any authentication in your gist. Are you sure you're using the client sdk and not the admin sdk that uses your application default credential to authenticate?

Comment: I've tried also removing the `node_modules` directory and `package-lock.json` and replacing it with a fresh `npm install`. I've tried with multiple firebase projects. I have app check in monitor mode on the project, in case that was interfering.

Comment: As in my Gist, I am using the client SDK with same version. Can you try running that locally? Like download and just `node filename.js`?

Comment: Thanks for your help with this.  I did try running it locally. I had to modify it to add the authentication step `signInWithEmailAndPassword` but once I did that I got the same result -- it just hangs waiting for the `uploadBytes` promise to resolve.